# Inversion of n x n matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the inverse of this $n \times n$ matrix, which is an $n \times n$ matrix of $1$s minus the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

[image]

Comment: This matrix is not usually invertible, unless I'm misunderstanding the entries. How many $1$s are there in an $n\times n$ matrix?

Comment: $\frac1{n-1}A - \frac{n-2}{n-1}I$.

Comment: Don't close this question, which is good.  I'll have the solution in a few minutes...

Answer (score 2):

Use the Sherman-Morrison formula:

$(A + B)^{-1} = A^{-1} - {1 \over 1 + Tr[B A^{-1}]} A^{-1} B A^{-1}$, where $B$ is an $n \times n$ matrix of $1$s and $A$ is the negative of the $n \times n$ identity matrix $I$.

Of course, here $A^{-1} = -I$.

Thus $(A + B)^{-1} = -I - {1 \over 1 + Tr[B]} B$.

Also, the trace of $B$ is $Tr[B] = n$.

Thus:  $(A + B)^{-1} = -I - {1 \over 1 + n} B$.